# bash I/O redirection - how to append to stderr

Tags: bash, io, stdout, stderr, streams

I have a script that loops over some big collection of data and performs some lenghty operations. Then i need to `sort | uniq -c` its output. So to let it know that its alive, I print a dot every N items on stderr (very primitive pseudo progress-bar), so it looks pretty much like this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do 
    [[ $(( (i+=1) % 10)) -eq 0 ]] && echo -n "." >&2
    shuf -i 1-10 -n1
    sleep 0.1
done | sort | uniq -c
```

and the output:

```
..........      9 1
     10 10
      8 2
     14 3
     13 4
      9 5
     11 6
      8 7
      8 8
     10 9
```

the "progress bar" messes up the output a little - so i was wondering:

- is there an easy way to add a nweline to that stderr before flushing that stdout? (probably `echo >&2` is all I need)
- or remove it ?

of course in reeality i dont know wow many items there are (at least not out-of-the box). So i was wondering if this can be acieved by some stream redirection

Comment: FWIW, you can replace `[[ $(( (i+=1) % 10)) -eq 0 ]]` with `[[ 'i++ % 10' -eq 0 ]]` or `(( i++ % 10 == 0 ))`.

Comment: `[ "$(( (i += 1) % 10 ))" -eq 0 ]` would be the POSIX one. But then again `{1..100}` is a zshism and `echo -n .` is not POSIX either (`printf .` is the standard equivalent). Not to mention `sleep 0.1` (no standard equivalent).

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather want `! (( i % 10 ))` as `i` is already incremented in the loop.

Comment: that was some pseudo-code... imagine `for j in {.....}` and rest stays the same ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the loop in braces (or parentheses) and put the extra echo inside them:

```
{ for i in {1..100}; do 
    [[ $(( (i+=1) % 10)) -eq 0 ]] && echo -n "." >&2
    shuf -i 1-10 -n1
    sleep 0.1
done; echo >&2; } | sort | uniq -c
```

With the whole brace group redirected to `sort`, it has to wait for everything inside to exit before seeing an end-of-file so it can proceed. That ensures the newline is printed before any of the output from `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: maaaaaaaa, you are my hero ;) it was THAT simple, and I yet couldnt figure it out :P thanks very much!